# Run this function only once when the website is opened and use it on all controllers Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-6

I want this function, which is connected to Crisp API, to run only once when the website is opened, and I use its in all controls. Because every time it wants to run, the application speed slows down.

```
      use Crisp;

      private function CrispClient()
        {
            $CrispClient = new Crisp();
    
            $CrispClient->authenticate("3a44293-706-4290-838-c063b58", "969b80676b5a671f2ee7a44f2452f7d152ed3c0c4a");

            return $CrispClient;
        }
```

Comment: `once when the website is opened` Do you mean every time a page is loaded?

Comment: Yes ,  I not speak English properly

Comment: Please check my answer - please accept it if it helped you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the command once per request, I suggest using a Middleware to inject your `$CrispClient` in the request:

**Middleware**:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            $CrispClient = new Crisp();
            $CrispClient->authenticate("...", "...");

            $request->merge(['crisp_client' => $CrispClient]);
            return $next($request);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
$crispClient = request()->crisp_client;
```

Comment: No ,return null.

Comment: Can you please `dd($request->all())` right before `return $next($request);` ?

Comment: I think Not import middleware to controller

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation on how to register a middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware